# Поиск в массиве по примерному значению

Tags: массивы, php, search

Как можно реализовать поиск в массиве по примерному значению, к примеру, у меня есть массив:

```
$array = array('131:2:3', '562:2:8', '217:6:3');
```

Мне необходимо, найти в массиве первое значение, т.е я знаю, что в строке число:число:число первое число будет число 131, а дальше мне без разницы какие цифры, пробовал с помощью array_search, но похоже, что он ищет именно похожее значение, а похожее я не могу, т.к не знаю какие будут 2 следующих значения, да и мне знать не надо.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Решение помогло, а вот почему то при разбивании строки через explode, он не хочет искать в этом полученном массиве значение, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам поможет функция [preg_grep](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-grep.php). В неё передаются массив и регулярное выражение, по которому будет осуществляться поиск элементов массива. Она возвращает все элементы массива, которые подходят под переданную регулярку.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло.